# double free or corruption (out) Error Encountered in Large Matrix Diagonalization in HPCluster (+ advice )

Tags: numpy, ubuntu, debugging, linear-algebra, lapack

I'm diagonalizing a very large matrix for a physics project, the size of the matrix is of the order 50000x50000 and is of numpy data type `complex128`. The calculations take some time, so I run the code with `nohup code.py &` and find 7~8 hours later that the nohup.out reads `double free or corruption (out)`

I'm using my university HPC server (running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) where I have access to 60 CPUs, approximately 500GBs of RAM and 1.2TB of storage so I don't think the issue is hardware limitations.

I'm running the code using Python 3.7.16, numpy 1.21.6. Below I write a code which replicates the output.

```
# FILENAME: code.py
# Multiprocessing Directives
import os
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '16' 
# Imports 
import numpy as np

# Create a Hermitian Hamiltonian Matrix 
# NOTE: Original code matrix is created using a library called kwant and is determined using system parameters and relevant physics and is nearly sparse
# For recreation purposes we create a random hermitian matrix of the same size
N = 76
M = N**2*8 # = 46208 is the matrix size
A = np.complex128(np.random.rand(M, M) + 1j*np.random.rand(M, M)) 
H = 0.5 *(A + A.conj()) # Ensures the matrix is hermitian

# Diagonalization: Problem part
ev, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(H)
# Some additional code which does not run due to the previous part failing.
...
```

Info which might be useful: running `np.show_config()` gives me:

```
blas_info:
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/dumanemre/anaconda3/envs/env-tkwant/lib']
    include_dirs = ['/home/dumanemre/anaconda3/envs/env-tkwant/include']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/dumanemre/anaconda3/envs/env-tkwant/lib']
    include_dirs = ['/home/dumanemre/anaconda3/envs/env-tkwant/include']
    language = c
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/dumanemre/anaconda3/envs/env-tkwant/lib']
    language = f77
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/dumanemre/anaconda3/envs/env-tkwant/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/dumanemre/anaconda3/envs/env-tkwant/include']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C
    not found = FMA3,AVX2,AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```

I have succesfully run the code using smaller ensembles where the size of the matrix was 20000x20000.

I have tried running using all the CPUs, 4 CPUs and a single CPU by updating the `os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '16'` line accordingly - unfortunately I received the same output.